# mailto: links and webmail

Tags: html

Is there a way to implement a mailto: link that works with webmail clients?

Edit - so a traditional mailto link is (as I suspected) not going to work. So has anyone seen anything similar to those rss buttons you see with a variety of the most popular sites on?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If a user has a webmail client set up as their mailto: handler, it should be used from any mailto: link. Are you interested in forcing a particular webmail client to be used?

Comment: That implementation would need the web mail authentication *in* the link itself. As you already guessed, NOT LIKELY!

Comment: I guess @SillyMonkey wants the gmail (for example) compose window to open with given to address when the mailto link is pressed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The links are handled by the user's browser.  GMail has a client-side install (GMail Notifier) that lets you specify that you want GMail to handle all mailto links.

But there's no way for a web page to specify that it's mailto link should be handled by a webmail app (even if it could, how would you know which one?).

Comment: You answered the exact same thing as I was going to:)
Prize to the fastest typer:)

Comment: This may change in HTML5, where things like registerProtocolHandler() allows site to define handlers for custom protocols.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#custom-handlers

Comment: Gmail Notifier doesn't seem to work for Gmail Business accounts. For that you'll need to either copy and paste the link into your webmail.

Comment: To be more specific, I meant it doesn't work with Google Apps email.

Answer (score 5):

That's really more of a web client issue, it's already available for Firefox:

http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2008/04/firefox-3-web-protocol-handlers/

but ultimately it's down to the user to decide how their browser handles mailto links.

Answer (score 5):

**Create a text file named MailtoWebMail.reg with the following content...**

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\mailto\shell\open\command]
>
> @="\"(BrowserExecutable)\" (Parameters)"

**where (BrowserExecutable) is replaced with the complete path to your browser (ie. C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe)
and (Parameters) is replaced with the appropriate line for the mail service as described below...**

**GMail**
"http://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=%1"

**Hotmail**
"http://hotmail.msn.com/cgi-bin/compose?To=%1&mailto=1"

**Yahoo Mail**
"http://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?To=%1"

**Netscape Mail**
"http://webmail.netscape.com/compose.adp?mailto=%1"

**Mail.com**
"http://mail01.mail.com/scripts/mail/Outblaze.mail?composeto=%1&compose=1"

**Opera Web Mail**
"http://mymail.operamail.com/scripts/mail/Outblaze.mail?compose=1&did=1&a=1&to=%1"

Note: There should not be a blank line after the [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE] line

MikeB

Comment: The hotmail link didn't work for me - whereas gmail was just fine (if logged in beforehand) - although not every feature like subject= seems to be supported.

Answer (score 2):

I am just brainstorming here. You might be able attach a Javascript handler to the link that asks the user if s/he wants to login to a webmail account (along with a list of providers). If you have the correct URLs for the webmail providers, you would then be able to invoke them on the basis of the user's choice. If the user answers no, return true from the handler and presumably the link would work normally.

See, for example, http://toric.blogspot.com/2005/07/gmail-compose-link.html and http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000238.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 Opera UserJS examples that you can inspect to give you and idea of how you can do it on a regular pages. (Obviously, UserJS-specific functions wouldn't work in a regular page, but you can use regular events.)

This one catches left-clicks on mailto links and opens them in Gmail for example. It can also handle forms.

http://shadow2531.com/opera/userjs/BeforeMailtoURL.js

This one catches all mailto actions, has a more generic parser (that supports any hname and not just to, cc, bcc, subject and body) and has a better format string syntax:

http://shadow2531.com/opera/userjs/BeforeMailtoURL.zip

Basically, you have to find a way to intercept mailto link actions. You can do this with click event listeners on links and submit listeners on forms (if you really want to support forms). (It's easier to use a click event listener on the whole window and just filter it to find mailto actions. That way, you catch mailto links that are dynamically added at some arbitrary time.)

Or, you can just run through the page and process all the mailto links.

But, if you want to intercept mailto actions in the address field, via window.open or document.location etc., you'll need something like HTML5's registerProtocolHandler or something like Opera's webmailprovider.ini support. You can use registerProtocolHandler in Firefox, but by default, it's restricted to the domain you set it on.

So, basically, you either convert mailto links to http(s) webmail compose URIs up front, or at the time the mailto action is invoked. The latter works much better.

Converting a mailto link to a webmail compose URI involves a few things. First, you need to know what query string variables the webmail accepts. Then, you need to parse the mailto URI to split it up into the parts you want. Then, you need to decode and re-encode (to normalize) those parts. Then, you need to join multiple occurrences of hvalues together. And, you need to handle things in a case-insensitive manner and check for and escape unsafe characters and %HH etc.

For the parsing, you can do a quick and dirty regex, but you'll get better results with a full mailto URI parser and normalizing functions.

So, if you just want to handle left-clicking on links, you can do that cross-browser. For more than that, you have to use any hooks the particular browser gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically, assuming the webmail client passes arguments through the authentication process (or the user is already authenticated), I don't see why this is so impossible.  It can't be done in the simple mailto: way, but it'd be possible to provide a selection of links to popular webmail services and use Javascript to intercept clicks on mailto: links such that the user is presented with a drop-down list of possible webmail services (or their local email client).  The links would carry the To:/Subject: address but formed in whatever structure that webmail service requires.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Google Apps email account (hosted email), than Gmail Notifier will not work. You can use a bookmarklet though, to change all of your mailto: links to links that point to your webmail.

Here's a bookmarklet I wrote to do just that, it will highlight all fixed links in red.

```
javascript:for(var i=0;i<document.links.length;i++){var a=document.links[i];if(a.href.indexOf('mailto:')==0){a.href='http://mail.google.com/a/sample.com/mail?extsrc=mailto&url='+a.href;a.style.backgroundColor='red';a.style.color='white'}};return true;
```

Just be sure to change http://mail.google.com/a/sample.com to whatever the proper hosted address is for you.

I suppose this will work with a number of other email clients if you just change that link around.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an old thread, but nobody has quite answered it yet, so here goes.

As blesh nearly says above, while there's no way to get "mailto:" to go to Gmail, there's another way to skin this cat that works just fine in many situations.  Just change the URL.  Remove the "mailto:" prefix and insert "https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=".

This seems to work like a charm, whether or not the user is coming in through Google Apps.  If the user is not logged in, he'll be walked through that step, and then Gmail will still kick off a new message.  The only downside I've noticed is that if (when?) Google decides to change their bookmarking scheme, this may need a bit of tweaking.

It may make sense to perform this transform either before or after the URL is in the DOM, depending on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Oh and double click the MailtoWebMail.reg to insert the command into your registry.

MikeB

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone seen **numbers** indicating what percentage of webmail users  have configured their systems with plugins etc. to properly have `mailto:` links sent to their browser / webmail system rather than to a desktop app? This seems critical in deciding whether to use `mailto:` links on a site or a contact form, but I'm having trouble coming up with numbers to guide the decision.